# Silverlight - where do you start (for free)?

Tags: silverlight, toolkit

First I've read loads of posts and sites that recommend going to http://silverlight.net/GetStarted/ to get started but I do not have visual studio and I'm not going to purchase it just to 'maybe' learn some silverlight that I'm not going to be able to use for a little while.

The reason being that I've already installed visual studio and all the other things required during a quiet period of work, then another project came up and by the time I got back to thinking about silverlight the trial period has finished.

I have not done C# or XAML (mainly Java, AS3 & MXML, hence the lack of MS tools) but I'd like to look into silverlight when I'm quiet to create some test projects and to determine where I can use it if anywhere.  Is there a toolset that will let me learn and use all that is required without purchasing the software (perhaps it would have a watermark like the flex datacharts used to have, unless you purchased them, maybe an eclipse plugin - although I imagine I'm being a bit optimistic here).

If there isn't such a thing then perhaps MS should look into this, Adobe recently let anyone unemployed/students etc to get flexbuilder for free to increase its uptake.  That would be great is MS did something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download [Blend preview 3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=A04AA0AE-87BE-4201-A65E-E792859122FC&displaylang=en) and [visual studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/onoj/archive/2009/05/19/visual-studio-2010-beta-1-download-options.aspx) for free and use it. You have the tools and knowledge now ;-)

Check out [Bizspark](http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/) too.

Answer (score 4):

If you are a student, you can get professional Microsoft tools for free through the Dreamspark program.  http://www.dreamspark.com

Answer (score 3):

Allegedly, you can now use one of Microsoft's free "Express" development systems to develop Silverlight apps.

http://www.bluerosegames.com/SilverlightBrassTacks/post/You-can-now-write-Silverlight-apps-in-Visual-Web-Developer-Express.aspx

Comment: This also looks good. Thought that I maybe needed to do C# & XAML to create a silverlight app, I'm taking it that as you can use this tool that this assumption is wrong.

Comment: No, from what I've read there are many ways to do Silverlight. If I recall correctly, there are even some Managed JavaScript examples around, which might help some with portability to AJAX or Flash.

Comment: @Shoban, it was easy to miss. Microsoft left the Express versions without decent Silverlight for way too long. In my opinion, they should be giving away all Silverlight tools to try to encourage Silverlight adoption.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the free-as-in-free-beer options from MS that other answers mention: if you only want to play around with Silverlight for now, consider trying [Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight) -- it may not yet be ready for production work, but nevertheless usable for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

One place you can go is to the [express web site](http://www.microsoft.com/express/) on Microsoft.com.  You can get free, albeit trimmed back, versions of the current release of Visual Studio and SQL Server there.

You can also get a trial version of [Expression Blend 2](http://www.microsoft.com/Expression/products/Overview.aspx?key=blend).  Blend is a design oriented tool for creating Silverlight applications.

You can also usually find betas of upcoming releases without much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight + Eclipse:

http://www.eclipse4sl.org/download/

And how to workaround Express for SL

http://www.informikon.com/blog/howto-silverlight-and-visual-studio-express.html

Good luck
  Braulio